# Traversing Tree Bug

Tags: javascript, debugging, tree, nodes

I've built a simple pseudoclassical Tree,

I have a method that applies a callBack to every node in the Tree and returns that node to a copy of its parent.

The problem comes at the end where the Tree is returned I don't get the last children in the original Tree?

code I pasted from snipets from chrome dev tools -

```
var Tree = function(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
};

Tree.prototype.map = function(callBack) {

let traverseTree = function(parent) {

    let newParent = new Tree(callBack(parent.value));

    if (parent.children) {

        for (let i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {

            newParent.addChild(callBack(parent.children[i].value));

            console.log(parent.children[i], 'each child', 'child in parent?', newParent)

            traverseTree(parent.children[i]);

        }

    }
    return newParent

};
return traverseTree(this)
}

Tree.prototype.addChild = function(value) {
let newChild = new Tree(value);

this.children.push(newChild);

return newChild;
};

var root1 = new Tree(1);

var branch2 = root1.addChild(2);
var branch3 = root1.addChild(3);
var leaf4 = branch2.addChild(4);
var leaf5 = branch2.addChild(5);
var leaf6 = branch3.addChild(6);
var leaf7 = branch3.addChild(7);

var newTree = root1.map(function(value) {
    return value * 2;
});

console.log(newTree, "NEW TREEE")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't do anything with the new node that is created with `newParent.addChild()`. So that created child will never be able to get children of its own.

You should actually not use that call at all, but leave it to the recursive call to create the node (which it does in its first statement), and then you should capture the return value from the recursive call, as *that* is the new child that has been created, and then append that child to the current node's children array.

One other comment: `if (parent.children)` is always going to lead to the execution of the `if` block, because every array, even when empty, is truthy in JavaScript. In fact, you don't need that `if` at all: the `for` loop will just not iterate if the array turns out to be empty.

So, taken that together, you get this:

```js
var Tree = function(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
};

Tree.prototype.map = function(callBack) {
    let traverseTree = function(parent) {
        let newParent = new Tree(callBack(parent.value));
        for (let i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
            // Change is here:
            newParent.children[i] = traverseTree(parent.children[i]);
        }
        return newParent;
    };
    return traverseTree(this);
}

Tree.prototype.addChild = function(value) {
    let newChild = new Tree(value);
    this.children.push(newChild);
    return newChild;
};

var root1 = new Tree(1);
var branch2 = root1.addChild(2);
var branch3 = root1.addChild(3);
var leaf4 = branch2.addChild(4);
var leaf5 = branch2.addChild(5);
var leaf6 = branch3.addChild(6);
var leaf7 = branch3.addChild(7);

var newTree = root1.map(function(value) {
    return value * 2;
});


console.log("new tree:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(newTree, null, 2));
```

I would like to take the opportunity to point you to some more modern syntax (`class`, spread syntax, arrow functions), and a constructor that can immediately accept the children nodes, making the `addChild` method unnecessary -- at least for this task:

```js
class Tree {
    constructor(value, ...children) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = children;
    }
    map(callBack) {
        const traverseTree = parent => 
            new Tree(
                callBack(parent.value),
                ...parent.children.map(traverseTree)
            );
        return traverseTree(this);
    }
}

var root1 = new Tree(1, 
    new Tree(2,
        new Tree(4), new Tree(5)
    ),
    new Tree(3,
        new Tree(6), new Tree(7)
    )
);

var newTree = root1.map(value => value * 2);

console.log("new tree");
console.log(newTree);
```

Comment: Could you give some feed-back?